# Express + Mongoose: async/await returning undefined

Tags: node.js, express, controller, routes, async-await

I'm trying to separate route code from database codes, but I'm stuck with an error when the route make an call to controller method.

I have the **productRoutes.js**:

```
router.route('/')
    .get(async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            let criteria = {};
            for (const el in req.query) {
                criteria[el] = req.query[el];
            }
            console.log('Getting all products', criteria);

            const result = await controller.getAll(criteria);
            console.log('router result:', result);
            const status = (result.ok ? (result.count > 0 ? 200 : 404 ) : 400);
            return res.status(status).send(result);
        } catch (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
    });
```

The **productController.js**:

```
exports.getAll = (criteria) => {
    model.find(criteria, '-__v').exec((err, records) => {
        const ok = (err ? false : true);

        let result = {}
        result.ok = ok;
        if (ok) {
            result.data = records;
            result.count = records.length;
        } else {
            result.count = 0;
            result.err = err;
        }

        console.log('controller result count:', result.count);

        return result;
    });
}
```

When executed it produces this:

```
Getting all products {}
router result: undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ok' of undefined
    at router.route.post.get (C:\dev\projects\mercante\server\routes\productRoutes.js:58:36)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
controller result count: 4
```

The execution isn't waiting for `controller.getAll(criteria)`.

I've tried some codes I found looking for similar questions, like try/catch the async call, but didn't works or I missed some detail.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason: Your controller's `getAll` method doesn't return any value.

You should do smth like this:

```
exports.getAll = async (criteria) => {
    // Return value!
    return await model.find(criteria, '-__v');
}
```

Comment: I understood now. So my controller must only return the data and the route must use it and add any additional information, if necessary.

Comment: It's up to you, you can play with your data in controller too. Just consider to return some value with async/await, or promise.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Rashad. Now it works:

**productController.js**:

```
exports.getAll = async (criteria) => {
    return await model.find(criteria, '-__v');
}
```

**productRoutes.js**:

```
.get(async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        let criteria = {};
        for (const el in req.query) {
            criteria[el] = req.query[el];
        }
        console.log('Getting all products', criteria);

        let result = {};
        const data = await controller.getAll(criteria);

        result.count = data.length;
        result.data = data;

        const status = (result.ok ? (result.count > 0 ? 200 : 404 ) : 400);
        return res.status(status).send(result);
    } catch (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
});
```